# Starting "cmd.exe" in Java and writing to it's standard input

Tags: java, windows, process

There are a couple of questions similar to this one ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669165/2375105) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971171/2375105) for example), but the answers do not work.

Here is my program:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/k");
Process p = pb.start();
Writer w = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
w.write("echo ABCD\n");
w.flush();
```

This runs, but no console window pops up.

If instead I do this: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start");` it creates a console window, but it doesn't accept the input ("echo ABCD\n") because the new console window is actually a subprocess of the `cmd` process I created.

How can I create a `cmd` process so that the console window will be created immediately (without the "start" command) so that I can send text to it and it will be displayed in the window (as if it came from the console's standard input)?

Comment: Try just `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c");`

Comment: @g00se That was one of the first things that I tried. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable used for cmd.exe in a console is conhost.exe, so adjust the command to:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "conhost.exe");
```

Working program:

```
String cmd = "echo ABCD" + System.lineSeparator();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "conhost.exe");
Process p = pb.start();
try (OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream()) {
    os.write(cmd.getBytes());
    os.flush();
}
```

Comment: Great, this works. However, the only thing I needed to change is to run "conhost.exe" instead of "cmd"... I won't accept this as answer as it is since most of it isn't really relevant... if you can revise the answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @traveh Done and am glad that helped but note that extra code  added before works for all situations - many examples in SO can fail due to incorrect stdout handling.

Comment: Turns out that in order to actually have the commands executed I needed to use `new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "conhost.exe");` and then use the writer to write the commands.